# Customizing leaflet overlay that is a geoJson file from a static file

Tags: colors, popup, leaflet, overlay, geojson

I am building a map app with Leaflet. I am pulling a geojson file of congressional districts from a static file. I would like to add a popup to each district that contains the district name - which is in the geojson file. I would also like to color the districts with unique colors.

I have tried this code for adding popups with the district names. It does not work.

```
  var polygons;
  $.getJSON(
    "http://localhost:8080/assets/geo/NationalCongressional.json",
    function(data) {
      polygons = L.geoJSON(data, {
        style: myCustomStyle,
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
          layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
        }
      });
    }
  );
  var overlays = {
    polygons: polygons
  };

  L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays).addTo(myMap);
```

The error is that polygons is undefined.

If I don't mess around with code like this to customize the layer, then I can directly add the geojson to my map with no problem. Like this...

```
  var NationalCongressional = new L.geoJson.ajax(
    "http://localhost:8080/assets/geo/NationalCongressional.json",
    {
      style: upperHouseStyle
    }

  var overlays = {
    NationalCongressiona: NationalCongressional
  };

  L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays).addTo(myMap);
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Here's the solution...

```
  var NationalCongressional = new L.geoJson.ajax(
    "http://localhost:8080/assets/geo/NationalCongressional.json",
    {
      style: upperHouseStyle,
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.NAMELSAD);
        if (feature.properties.NAMELSAD == "Congressional District 8") {
          console.log("found a match");
          layer.setStyle({ color: "orange" });
        }
      }
    }
  );

  var overlays = {
    NationalCongressional: NationalCongressional
  };

  L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlays).addTo(myMap);
```